# Can I move my asp.net application to the cloud?

Tags: asp.net, .net, azure, amazon-web-services, cloud

Our company is thinking about moving to the cloud. Would we still be able to meet all our current requirements (below).  We want to be able to easily scale in the future without high costs.

- 5 ASP.net 4.0 websites running (using sql databases, see below)
- SQL Server 2008 Express (8 databases on this)
- 2 Scheduler services running (send nightly reports via email e.g. new orders in db)
- MongoDB and Memcached are also installed on server

Currently the websites are on a separate server from the database server for security reasons.

We were thinking about [Windows Azure](http://www.windowsazure.com/) and [Amazon Web Services (AWS)](http://aws.amazon.com/) as providers, which would best fit our requirements?

Are there any other factors we need to consider?

Comment: You can certainly move all your stuff to Amazon EC2 instances if you can pay their prices.  It'd even be pretty easy to start with something small and cheap and build up.  EC2 instances are fully remote controllable VMs in the cloud.  Very cool stuff.

Comment: If you're already doing everything in .net than Azure is probably going to be a better choice because it'll feel more natural to your developers. I'm moving to Azure from IIS and it's pretty cool: if you don't want to take advantage of Azure's unique features (AppFabric for caching for instance) then there's really very little to change.

Comment: can i run windows services easily using azure?

Comment: roughly what is cheaper amazon or azure

Comment: @frenchie good to know about how easy Azure to port to w/o features. Running EC2 instances are exactly like running an IIS server somewhere, so that's very easy as well.

Comment: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/details/ and http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/

Comment: @IanPorter: not sure about pure cost comparison because I haven't looked into Amazon's costs. Keep in mind the cost of developers too; with Azure, your developers can either take the short route (pure port into 5 web roles) or the better route (move session state to appfabric vs. building sticky session mechanism with EC2 for instance; or implement WCF in case you want to go with a SOA). IMO, lot more things are built-in with Azure so I'd say the developer costs should be lower with Azure as requirements evolve over time.

Comment: @kenny, Azure can do VM hosting as well : http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/features/virtual-machines/

Comment: @IanPorter - regarding "can i run windows services easily using azure" - yes you can. You may want to consider refactoring into Worker Roles, but don't need to. Realize that running on Azure means you are running on Windows Server 2008, so should be very familiar. ( I mentioned a little more context in a blog post last year: http://blog.codingoutloud.com/2011/08/21/four-tips-for-developing-windows-services-more-efficiently/ )

Comment: @IanPorter: It's very hard to determine which is cheaper.  We went Amazon after doing a cost analysis because for *our* particular environment there was an order of magnitude difference in the costs over just 12 months.  However, there are numerous types apps that would be much cheaper on Azure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Re: SQL Databases:** on Windows Azure this would map to SQL Azure. Costs start at $5/month for up to a 100 MB instance - and goes all the way up to 150 GB - and goes beyond that with Federations.

**Re: 5 ASP.net 4.0 websites running:** these map naturally into Windows Azure Web Roles. The "small" instance is $0.12/hour/instance, and you'll usually want two instances (to avoid single point of failure for a few scenarios). Depending on your load, you may be able to put all 5 sites on the same instances. If you have very low usage sites, consider the $0.05/hour/instance "extra small" instance.

**Re: Currently the websites are on a seperate server from the database server for security reasons:** of course this is also doable.

**Re: 2 Scheduler services running:** Running Windows Services is no problem.

**Re: send nightly reports via email e.g. new orders in db:** No problem doing, though is not baked into Windows Azure directly, but there are many simple ways to do this (even for free, such as via [SendGrid](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2012/01/25/announcing-native-windows-azure-libraries-and-special-free-pricing-using-sendgrid-for-windows-azure-customers.aspx)).

**Re: We want to be able to easily scale in the future without high costs:** you will need to do the math regarding your actual costs, but Windows Azure can surely scale.

**Re: MongoDB and Memcache are also installed on server:** These can both be run on Azure. Check out https://github.com/mongodb/mongo for MongoDB. Also, the Azure Caching service is also avail (managed for you).

**Re: We were thinking about Azure and Amazon as providers, which would best fit our requirements:** These are functionally very similar (in capability and cost), with a few noteworthy differences.

1. Windows Azure is Platform as a Service meaning that you don't need to worry about Virtual Machines, but rather Applications. In other words, you upload your (basically) Zipped app package to the cloud for execution. With Amazon, you will be dealing with the Virtual Machine yourself. In Azure, you get a copy of Windows Server 2008 which is managed for you, but you can also do admin things to it if you need to. This is far less of an advantage if your app is an old messy install that isn't really clean (though may not be a good high-value cloud candidate anyway).
2. Windows Azure has an emulator that works great - F5 right from visual studio to work with storage system and VMs and more popular features.

**Re: Are there any other factors we need to consider:** Yes. With any cloud application, you need to be prepared to deal with scaling out (not up), dealing with transient retries (you may need to retry an operation to a cloud service - any cloud service). The benefits of this are much better (and more cost-effective) scalability and higher reliability (when you run across nodes, you don't have a single point of failure). Be sure to understand when/where storage on a VM is persistent vs. ephemeral. There are more considerations, but these are primary ones.

You may want to check out the [Windows Azure Pricing calculator](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/).

Good luck! And welcome to the cloud.

Answer (score 1):

with the exception of the scaling question, and the 2 physical servers, you can move this functionality into a hosted environment and you will technically be in "the cloud".  This could be a dedicated or VPS (Virtual Private Server), or even a shared server if you are small.

Those can allow for growth over time...you just need to upgrade what you have with the provider.

You also could use a colo-server with a hosting provider, which basically means you put your hardware in an hosting provider rack, and use their electricity and bandwidth.  They charge based on bandwidth usage.

Since you are using SQL Express, remember that each database is limited to 8gb.  So that will limit your growth at some point.  That would entail an upgrade from Express to regular SQL if you don't want to re-engineer anything.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered [AppHarbour](https://appharbor.com/)? It has [Memcached](https://appharbor.com/addons/memcacher), [MongoDB](https://appharbor.com/addons/mongohq), [SQL Server](https://appharbor.com/addons/sqlserver) and [so on](https://appharbor.com/addons), and is quicker to deploy to than Azure. I *like* Azure, but there is quite a learning curve and I have found the connection to SQL Azure to be pretty bad - which means re-engineering your DAL to use something like the [SQL Transient Failure Library](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4235.retry-logic-for-transient-failures-in-sql-azure.aspx) = a bit of a faff for existing projects.

AppHarbour does not have blob storage - so if you are uploading files you will need to use Azure Blob Storage or Amazon S3 or some equivalent as well.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Not an expert but being that Asp.net is a Microsoft product it should be easier to migrate to azure, although from what I have heard AWS shouldn't be difficult. Another thing you may want to consider is cost. Last time I checked AWS is significantly less costly unless you already pay for MSDN subscriptions.

Answer (score 0):

All the requirements you sum up are not any issue to deploy in Windows Azure. You can find a lot of information on the internet on how to do this.

Keep in mind, if you want to deploy your services to windows azure, you'll need to do some code review of your applications to fix session state, output cache and so forth on your web applications.

Since you want to scale them out and they are sitting behind a non-sticky round-robin load balancer, you will run into issues with your session state if it is saved on the machine itself. You'll need to part session state to SQL Azure or to the Windows Azure table storage for example.

Installing MongoB and Memcache in Azure is not an issue, you'll find a lot of information on how to do it, but it'll require some to set up your role and the scripting

Answer (score 0):

codingoutloud has given a very detailed answer. I would add two very key considerations to think about when moving any application to Azure (or, indeed, many other cloud providers).

**Local state**
With normal Azure, they reserve the right to shut down any one instance of a role at any time in order to move or upgrade it. This means you always need at least two instances of any one role and they will be transparently load balanced. If your current websites are currently running on individual servers then they may rely on session state or files in local directories etc. Now, there are ways around this (like putting session state in SQL, using the cookie provider for temp data, using a shared drive for files etc) or, indeed, bypassing a lot of the benefits of Azure and using their "virtual server" concepts which means you don't get the scale benefits etc.
But, sites that rely heavily on local state may be challenging to move to the cloud.

**Time Zones**
All Azure servers run on UTC time. If you are used to running on dedicated servers serving users from a single time zone then chances are that you use things like DateTime.Now() which won't really correspond to what the user wants.

I don't see any of the above as limitations of Azure, I find them very useful in forcing you to build global and scalable solutions from the start. However, when porting an existing application, the above may be quite a challenge to adapt to, even though there are workarounds.

As also mentioned elsewhere, there is a learning curve to Azure and somehow the documentation - plentiful as it is - just doesn't quite seem to help for some reason. Once you "get it", though, I find Azure really nice and there are a bunch of subtle features that will help you build scalable solutions, like the whole queuing infrastructure, the blob storage and the table storage. In some ways the learning is hampered by having too much choice.

Good luck!